# Return a value from the method initiated by SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, listbox

I have ListBox item in xaml that gets ListBoxItems from a method that reads items from xml file.

I have the list loaded successfully, and I also have a function that can add items to the list via the application. Now I need a way to remove the items. I want to get an item to remove by selecting a ListBoxItem from the list. What I had in mind is to use the SelectionChanged event and then use the following code:

```
string selected;

   private void XMLista_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        brisanjeDugme.IsEnabled = true;
        selected = XMLista.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
```

then I would use this to open up the machineList.xml file and then based on the value there remove the parent node if the node equals to the selected ListBoxItem.

so here is the method for removal:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        XDocument root = XDocument.Load("machineList.xml");
        root.Descendants("stampac").Where(p => p.Element("IP").Value == selected).Remove(); // <- selected variable is used here.
        root.Save("machineList.xml");

        XMLista.Items.Clear();
        ListBox_Load(sender, e);
        brisanjeDugme.IsEnabled = false;

    }
```

However, I'm having issues with using the selected variable in the above method I get an System.NullReferenceException error shown in the XMLista_SelectionChanged method, line where I defined the selected variable. I don't understand why do I get that, when I'm making sure that the button can only be pressed if I have a selected listboxitem (and I tested the value received in the messagebox, which shows correct value).

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Nikola. You wrote a long question, with details on what you want to do in your project, but you didn't provide a stack for the exception... Try to rewrite this question so that we may help you, remove the details that are unnecessary to understand the issue.

Comment: @swiszcz I have tried to post my question better. Let me know if there's somethign missing, and thanks for the help (and tip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the elements have been initialized and that there is a selected item:

```
private void XMLista_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (brisanjeDugme != null)
        brisanjeDugme.IsEnabled = true;
    if(XMLista != null && XMLista.SelectedItem != null)
        selected = XMLista.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tested this out and it works. But I don't get it? I was quite positive that I get the value needed for the removing to work (I even included the messagebox to say it to me once selected). How is this working differently?

Comment: The SelectionChanged event handler may be invoked before the elements have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post edit.

I'd recommend you to use `ObservableCollection<string>` to keep your list of items to display and bind this observable collection to XMLista.ItemsSource (or assign in the code behind). Now operate on this ObsevableCollection only (add or remove items). That's the recommended way of using collection controls in WPF and nobody has issues with that.

I'm guessing that the exception you get may be caused by operating erroneously on the XMLista.Items level.